# delete multiple rows in mysqldb

Tags: mysql, database

How can we optimize the delete query.

```
delete FROM student_score
    WHERE lesson_id IS NOT null
      AND id NOT IN(SELECT MaxID FROM temp)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1000
```

This select statement return "SELECT MaxID FROM temp" 35k lines and temp is a temporary table.

and select * FROM student_score WHERE
lesson_id IS NOT null return around 500k rows

I tried using limit and order by clause but doesn't result in faster ways

Comment: I see `id` and `lession_id` -- were they supposed to be the same column?

Comment: Did you check the execution plan for problems?

Answer (score 1):

`IN(SELECT...`)` is, in many situations, really inefficient.

Use a multi-table `DELETE`.  This involves a `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`, which is much more efficient.

Once you have mastered that, you *might* be able to get rid of the `temp` and simply fold it into the query.

Also more efficient is

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM temp
       WHERE student_score.lesson_id = temp.MAXID )
```

Also, `DELETEing` a large number of rows is inherently slow.  1000 is not so bad; 35K is.  The reason is the need to save all the potentially-deleted rows until "commit" time.

Other techniques for big deletes: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Note that one of then explains a more efficient way to walk through the `PRIMARY KEY` (via `id`).  Note that your query may have to step over lots of ids that have `lesson_id IS NULL`.  That is, the `LIMIT 1000` is not doing what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without `order by` :

```
DELETE FROM student_score
WHERE lesson_id IS NOT null
AND id NOT IN (SELECT MaxID FROM temp)
```

Or like this using `left join` which is more optimized in term of speed :

```
DELETE s
FROM student_score s
LEFT JOIN temp t1 ON s.id = t1.MaxID 
WHERE lesson_id IS NOT null and t1.MaxID is null;
```